# Javascript access global variable from inside the module

Tags: javascript

I am trying to access a global variable or a function from inside the module, but it still writes error that testFunction is not defined.

```
index.html:
<script src="main.js" type="module">

main.js:
import { runTestFunction } from './js/TestModule.js';
function testFunction() {
 alert('hello');
 }
runTestFunction();

TestModule.js:
export function runTestFunction() {
testFunction();
}
```

Comment: Well, it's not global, it's defined in the module. Same reason why you can't just call `runTestFunction` from *main.js* - you have to import it first!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You declare `testFunction()` in main.js but you are trying to call it in TestModule.js

You have a few choices:

1. Declare `testFucntion()` in TestModule.js
2. Implement the body of `testFunction()` in `runTestFunction()`
3. If you need to declare a function in main.js and then call it in TestModule.js then pass it to `runTestFunction()` as a parameter like:

:

```
TestModule.js:
export function runTestFunction(testFunction) {
    testFunction();
}

main.js:
import { runTestFunction } from './js/TestModule.js';
const testFunction=()=>{
     alert('hello');
 }
runTestFunction(testFunction);
```

EDIT:
To follow up on your comment about scope chain.

The reason why it is "not declared" because you have the import before the declaration. The code is executed from top to bottom. This means the function is declared after you tried to reference it.

Comment: Thank you both, I know how to solve it, I was just wondering why it does not work, because I thought that thanks to the scope chain which goes up until the global scope it should work. Because for instance following code works and I thought that the Obj here should behave the same way as module. But I was probably wrong. Thank you

Comment: function testFunction() {
  alert('hello');
}
let obj = function() {
  let fn = function() {
    testFunction();
  }
  return { fn:fn}
}();
obj.fn();

Comment: I added an explanation to your first comment.

Comment: Yes, you are right, it did not occur to me, now it is clear, thank you very much